# How to extract raw YUV files from MPEG2 TS file?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a 1920x1080 mpeg2 .ts file. I need to get the raw YUV files for each frame.
I tried ffmpeg but no luck. I end up with many small files. I expect each frame to be 1920x1080x1.5 = 3110400 Bytes.

```
[root@dwarch frames]# ffmpeg -i video.ts -f image2 foo-%03d.yuv
FFmpeg version git-N-28713-g65daa94, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Mar 30 2011 09:20:16 with gcc 4.6.0
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libfaac --enable-libxvid --enable-libx264 --enable-libvpx --enable-libtheora --enable-postproc --enable-shared --enable-x11grab --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-runtime-cpudetect --disable-debug
  libavutil    50. 40. 0 / 50. 40. 0
  libavcodec   52.116. 0 / 52.116. 0
  libavformat  52.104. 0 / 52.104. 0
  libavdevice  52.  4. 0 / 52.  4. 0
  libavfilter   1. 76. 0 /  1. 76. 0
  libswscale    0. 13. 0 /  0. 13. 0
  libpostproc  51.  2. 0 / 51.  2. 0
Input #0, mpegts, from 'video.ts':
  Duration: 00:04:51.58, start: 0.333333, bitrate: 36041 kb/s
  Program 10 
    Stream #0.0[0x20]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 35000 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 90k tbn, 47.95 tbc
    Stream #0.1[0x21]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1, s16, 224 kb/s
Incompatible pixel format 'yuv420p' for codec 'mjpeg', auto-selecting format 'yuvj420p'
[buffer @ 0x97148c0] w:1920 h:1080 pixfmt:yuv420p
[setdar @ 0x9714df0] a:16/9
[setdar @ 0x9714df0] auto-inserting filter 'auto-inserted scaler 0' between the filter 'src' and the filter 'Parsed filter 0 setdar'
[scale @ 0x9711db0] w:1920 h:1080 fmt:yuv420p -> w:1920 h:1080 fmt:yuvj420p flags:0x4
[setdar @ 0x9714df0] w:1920 h:1080 -> dar:16/9 sar:1/1
Output #0, image2, to 'foo-%03d.yuv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf52.104.0
    Stream #0.0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 1920x1080 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 23.98 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
```

Comment: I have a workaround for this  now.
`Incompatible pixel format 'yuv420p' for codec 'mjpeg', auto-selecting format 'yuvj420p'
[buffer @ 0x97148c0] w:1920 h:1080 pixfmt:yuv420p` is the issue. Using "identify" program, I have those output images as jpeg files. The solution is to eliminate the parameter -f image2 and using only one output file out.yuv. And then use dd to cut the output into different small file sized at 1920*1080*1.5 each.

Answer (score 6):

You may also use the option `-vframes` to get a single yuv frame as below:

```
ffmpeg -i video.ts -pix_fmt yuv420p -vframes 1 foo-1.yuv
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use image as the format(-f image2) it assumes mjpeg format, which is image compression format. So, yes your solution is correct, you need to remove -f image2.